# no me funciona npm en ubuntu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

cada ves que ejecuto `npm install -g create-react-app` o `npx create-react-app my-app` npm  no me funciona me aparece el mismo error `errno -13` también me aparece  `npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules` tambien me aparece estas dos `npm ERR! syscall mkdir` y `npm ERR! code EACCES` 
y llevo tiempo con este error y solamente esto me pasa en ubuntu y no se porque si tengo la ultima version de nodejs y npm. Si alguien supiera resolverme me serviria de mucha ayuda , gracias

Comment: Tu problema es de permisos, seguramente has instalado Node usando permisos de administrador (`sudo`), por lo cual todo el paquete quedó configurado para ser ejecutado como super usuario, incluyendo `npm`. Te sugiero que instales [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md), que es un potente administrador de versiones de Node, que no necesita permisos de super usuario para ser instalado y que te permitirá incluso alternar entre versiones de Node para proyectos y pruebas específicas. Saludos

Comment: intenta ejecutare el siguiente comando ```npm cache clean -f
```

Comment: Otra opción es cambiar el directorio global de `npm` para que se aloje en una ruta donde tu usuario tenga permisos. Más información en la [documentación](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally). Sin embargo, tal como se sugiere en la misma documentación, la solución preferida es el administrador de versiones. Saludos

Comment: @MIGUELLOPEZARIZA el error es de permisos (`EACCES`), limpiar la caché no solucionará el problema. Saludos